# Insert ArrayList mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

Im trying to batch insert 100 of the doc Objects. Am I using the insert statement incorrectly?

```
Mongo mongoClient = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "user" );    
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("userName","James").append("random1", "feeof").append("random2", "ofeijfefe");

    List<DBObject> postsList = new ArrayList<DBObject>(); 
    for ( int i = 0; i != 100; i++)
    {

        postsList.add(doc);
    }

    coll.insert(postsList);
```

It doesn't insert anything ,when  i inspect the last line it shows the value as *N/A*.

Comment: How do you check it hasn't inserted anything?

Comment: db.test.count() in console

Comment: You might not be looking in the right DB. Did you execute `usedb user` before looking at the count?

Comment: edit* Yes checked that and it isn't because of that.

Comment: I'm sorry it should be `use user`.

Comment: yep that's done and it works fine with 1 entry.

Comment: Check my answer. This works on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what is happening here.

The object `doc` is being added to `postsList` 100 times. Remember it is the same object at all those 100 places in the list.

Mongo creates an `_id` attribute for a document if it isn't already there. Once it puts this attribute in the first `BasicDBObject` in the list every other entry in the list gets modified with the same `_id`.

I believe because this `_id` attribute is same for all the entries in the list (which is like a primary key), only the first entry gets inserted.

You can solve this by adding a copy of the `doc` to the list. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    postsList.add((BasicDBObject) doc.copy());
}
```