# Insert an ArrayList to mongoDB in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a single ArrayList containing JSONS into a mongodb collection with this,

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("structure");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("chapter");
List<Document> data = new ArrayList<>();
collection.insertMany(data);
```

```java
String str = "[{\"id\":1,\"data\":\"data1\"},{\"id\":2,\"data\":\"data2\"}]";
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(str);
collection.insert(dbObject);
```

But I get the exception,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]

Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

[Insert ArrayList mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102809/insert-arraylist-mongodb)
The question above is about bulk insert of JSONS, not as a single one.
My question is unique

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert ArrayList mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102809/insert-arraylist-mongodb)

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani  The question above is about bulk insert of JSONS, not as a single one. My question is unique

Answer (score 2):

The exception gives a hint of what the problem is: a list cannot be used as a record (or a map-like data structure).

To quote the [MongoDB documentation on documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) that compose a collection:

> **Document Structure**
>
> MongoDB documents are composed of field-and-value
>   pairs and have the following structure:
>
> ```
> {
>    field1: value1,
>    field2: value2,
>    field3: value3,
>    ...
>    fieldN: valueN
> }
> ```

So what you need to do, in your case, *because you just want to insert **many** documents in one call*, is to use `collection.insertMany`:

```
List<Document> documents = ...; //convert your list to a List<Document>
collection.insertMany(documents);
```

Comment: The method insertMany(List<DBObject>) is undefined for the type DBCollection

Comment: @G.Brown I have `List<Document>` as the type for `documents`. Can you please correct what you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It seems the method of insertMany is absent.

Comment: It throws error like  'The method insertMany(List<Document>) is undefined for the type DBCollection'

Comment: No. The method is surely there on `collection`. Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Please look at my code in the question. The first five lines. I'm using mongo-java-driver-3.9.1

Comment: Please check this:http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertMany-java.util.List- That error wouldn't make sense. Do you perhaps have the incorrect import for `Document`?

Comment: And you should declare your `collection` as `MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("chapter");`. This may in fact be your problem.

Comment: That's correct. But check the comment about how you declared `collection`. That may be where your problem is.

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from DBCollection to MongoCollection<Document>`       is showing for  `MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("chapter");`

Comment: What's the name (or the coordinates) of the driver jar that you're using? And is your `MongoClient` a `com.mongodb.MongoClient`?

Comment: Jar is `mongo-java-driver-3.9.1`. Yes, I'm using `com.mongodb.MongoClient`

Comment: I don't know what that jar is. The one I'm using is `mongodb-driver` (`org.mongodb:mongodb-driver`). Check the documentation here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

```
List<DBobject> data = new ArrayList<>();
Colletions.insertMany(data);
```

Comment: The method insertMany(List<DBObject>) is undefined for the type DBCollection